# How to increment a variable in another script through importing?

Tags: python, django, scope, automation, global

I work on 2 files, say ba.py and 2.py

**ba.py:**

```
import sys

count  = 1 # This is global count

def callme():
    pass
    # Doing Some operation
```

**2.py**

```
import ba
print ba.count ## This is working fine
ba.callme() ## This is also working fine.
```

I am running a automation, job like this:

`for i in $(find /home/some/SomeElse/HeyMore -type f); do python 2.py $i; done`

What this command does, is take the files from the folder specified and pass it as argument to a function in `2.py`.

Internally, I want to open the file in python and perform some operations. However, I don't want to overload my system, so after 10 jobs I want to sleep for 10 seconds. I am maintaining the count using `count` in `ba.py`. After it is called for the first time, it should be incremented to `2`, and so on.

However, when it hits 10 it should sleep as my logic is written below.

```
print ba.count
ba.count = ba.count + 1  ## Here increment should happen
if ba.count % 10 == 0:
        time.sleep(10)
else:
        ba.callme()
```

Every time I run this automation script, I only see `1`'s, and the script is not sleeping after 10 seconds.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Only thing I observe is everytime script is done executing count is resetted to 1.

Comment: Every time you do `python scriptname` you're starting a fresh process. Variables from previous processes are not retained. If you need to keep data between script runs, you should put it in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2.py` is run for each file and has no knowledge of the counter set in a previous run. One solution is to only run 2.py once and pipe in the files you want processed:

```
import sys
import time

def callme(filename):
    print filename

for count,line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    if count and not(count % 10):
        print('sleeping')
        time.sleep(1) # I got bored.... make that 10
    callme(line.strip())
```

And your script becomes

```
find /home/some/SomeElse/HeyMore -type f | python 2.py
```

If you don't want `find` hanging around pumping data, you could pull the files in all at once and then process them

```
filenames = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]
...
```